# packages are installed but unable to import modules

Tags: robotframework

python modules are installed but unable to import genie.libs.robot.GenieRobot & pyats.robot.pyATSRobot. I tried to install packaged using "sudo" with no luck. how to fix this?

below are logs. I am new to coding/python. please help.

```
(devwks-2595) ljames@MAC-PC workshop % robot --outputdir robot_initial robot_initial_snapshot.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/ljames/Documents/Pycharm-workspace/CL-DevNet-2595-robotFramework-master/devwks-2595/workshop/robot_initial_snapshot.robot' on line 6: Importing test library 'genie.libs.robot.GenieRobot' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genie.libs.robot'


[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/ljames/Documents/Pycharm-workspace/CL-DevNet-2595-robotFramework-master/devwks-2595/workshop/robot_initial_snapshot.robot' on line 7: Importing test library 'pyats.robot.pyATSRobot' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyats.robot'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None


(devwks-2595) ljames@MAC-PC workshop % pip list
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ---------

genie.libs.clean             20.5
genie.libs.conf              20.5
genie.libs.filetransferutils 20.5
genie.libs.ops               20.5
genie.libs.parser            20.5
genie.libs.robot             20.5
genie.libs.sdk               20.5

pyats                        20.5
pyats.aereport               20.5
pyats.aetest                 20.5
pyats.async                  20.5
pyats.connections            20.5
pyats.datastructures         20.5
pyats.easypy                 20.5
pyats.kleenex                20.5
pyats.log                    20.5
pyats.reporter               20.5
pyats.results                20.5
pyats.robot                  20.5
pyats.tcl                    20.5
pyats.topology               20.5
pyats.utils                  20.5
```

Comment: How do you import the library in RF?

Comment: I am importing library in Robot Framework using:     Library        genie.libs.robot.GenieRobot  
Library        pyats.robot.pyATSRobot.